# What are mirrored orientations of a UIImage?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIImageOrientation) {
    UIImageOrientationUp,            // default orientation
    UIImageOrientationDown,          // 180 deg rotation
    UIImageOrientationLeft,          // 90 deg CCW
    UIImageOrientationRight,         // 90 deg CW
    UIImageOrientationUpMirrored,    // as above but image mirrored along other axis. horizontal flip
    UIImageOrientationDownMirrored,  // horizontal flip
    UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored,  // vertical flip
    UIImageOrientationRightMirrored, // vertical flip
};
```

I think I don't really understand what are these `Mirrored` orientations and what they are for. I've always thought that they represent cases when image flipped over vertical or horizontal axis. But I take photo with my phone, which shows `UIImageOrientationUp`. I then open this photo in editor and flip it over vertical axis expecting orientation to change to `UIImageOrientationUpMirrored`. But it doesn't take any effect. Nothing changes. Moreover, I don't remember last time when I saw orientation value greater than 3. I am just curious how to take this image.

So, what are `Mirrored`values? Why do I need to consider them? Can you give any example of image which orientation is `Mirrored`?

Comment: "open this photo in editor and flip it over vertical axis" What editor? You are describing it correctly. This would apply particularly when taking a photo from the front facing camera in the camera app, which automatically flips the photo to have it appear as it would naturally rather than as mirrored image.

Comment: @beyowulf editor? I use Aviary. Well, you can take a photo with front camera and rear. In my case, holding iPhone 6s vertically, I get imageOrientation 3 for them both. Not 7. That's the problem. The photo I took with front camera has the same orientation.

Comment: Well, I can't speak for the implementations of either of those apps but one could do something like UIImage * flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored]; and want a convenient way of converting back. You seem very put out by this, but I think it is just meant to be a convenient why of determining a photos orientation without constantly inspecting its size and whatnot not to mention handling bridging between CGImageRef.